# Fechar modais com jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Possuo uma modal onde o usuário poderá selecionar um plano de assinatura onde possui o botão

```html
<button type="button" class="button-assign" data-bind="widgetLocaleText:'subscribeButton'"></button>
```

isso abre uma segunda modal onde ele pode assinar ou voltar

```html
<button type="button" id="btn-voltar" class="btns-return" data-bind="widgetLocaleText: 'btnReturn'"></button>
```

gostaria de no momento em que esta segunda modal abrir a primeira ficasse escondida e só aparecesse se o usuário clicar em voltar, porém ela não some e fica no fundo. Não utilizo o bootstrap ou outro framework. 
Segue o código das modais

```js
modalConfirmation: function() {
      $(".btn-assinar").on("click", function() {
        var my_popup = $("#modal-confirmation").popup();
        my_popup.open();
      });
    },

    modalCancel: function() {
      $(".btn-assinar").on("click", function() {
        var my_popup = $("#modal-upgrade").popup("show");
        my_popup.hide();
      });
    },

    cancelClub: function() {
      $(".btns-voltar").click(function() {
        $("#modal-upgrade").open();
      }); 
    }
```

Comment: Você está utilizando algum framework para utilizar o modo? Como por exemplo o bootstrap?

Comment: não estou utilizando o bootstrap ou outro framework

Comment: Olá, Seja bem-vinda ao stackoverflow, gostaria de te sugerir que você dê uma lida no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como a plataforma funciona e em [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e após isso, edite sua pergunta incluindo seu código para que a comunidade possa te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar um data-dismiss="modal" no botão que abre seu segundo modal, isso deve resolver seu primeiro problema, agora pode colocar uma ação no botão de voltar para abrir novamente o seu primeiro modal.

```
$("#btn-voltar").click(function() {
   $('#id-primeiro-modal').modal('show');
});
```

Pra isso funcionar você precisa adicionar um id no seu primeiro modal.

Comment: A primeira modal some quando a segunda abre, porém não consegui faze-la abrir novamente